# Installing wordpress in subdirectory on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi guys I've installed wordpress on my EBS instance in subfolder /tips, but when I go to the the directory which is 'mysite.com/tips' or 'mysite.com/tips/index.php' the address changes to 'mysite.com:8888/tips' and fails, although the 'mysite.com/tips/wp-login.php' works. but that still tries to login to localhost:8888?! Does anyone know why this may be happening? And what settings I can change to sort this? Hope you can help!

Comment: You sure you've got your wordpress configured so that it thinks its own URL is `http://mysite.com/tips/`? Can you post your htaccess file?

Comment: ah i copied my local database and didnt realise that wordpress stores some of its address data in the database not just on the config file.. you have to create a fresh database installation on the server. thanks for your help!